# how to add cognito userEmails to DynamoDB Table via Resolvers?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

When configuring the request mapping template inside a create muatation resolver one can add Cognito  attributes such as sub(ctx.identity.sub) and username(ctx.identity.username). So that these are added directly into the DynamoDB table. Now is it there some variation of the code for emails?

Thanks alot.

Comment: What authentication type are you using?

Comment: I'm using IAM for authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to access the email associated with an Amazon Cognito User Pools session, you can do so like this:

```
$context.identity.claims.email
```

You can then use the email in the mutation operation, or whatever else you need to do with it.

I noticed you said you're using IAM for authentication, so I wanted to note that this does not really apply for IAM authenticated calls to AppSync, but it will work for Amazon Cognito authenticated calls.

Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: ok thanks will probably have to rework my authentication then

Comment: That's not correct:  the email property is not present with "Amazon Cognito"